# What is the smallest scale at which the effect of dark matter can be observed?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies

Dark matter is primarily postulated in the context of large scale things e.g. spiral galaxies, in order to provide additional forces where vanilla gravity doesn't seem sufficiently strong to explain what is observed.

Are there any smaller-scale contexts where we can attribute what is observed with the effect of dark matter? For example, is there any reason to believe dark matter is affecting anything on the scale of the solar system?

More precisely, I'm wondering what is generally accepted to be the smallest scale at which the effect of dark matter is at play.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there examples of dark matter at intra-galactic scales?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/577297/are-there-examples-of-dark-matter-at-intra-galactic-scales)

Comment: Yes, take a look at this. This is article about how quantum physics can detect dark matter. https://news.uchicago.edu/story/uchicago-fermilab-physicists-build-quantum-bit-can-search-dark-matter#:~:text=Qubits%20offer%20a%20fast%2C%20highly,%E2%80%94called%20dark%20matter%E2%80%94itself.